# Manually costomizing the wordpress webiste to bilingual

Tags: wordpress

This is my first post on Stackoverflow. Pardon me if there is any unclear words below.

Currently I am editing my company homepage that is built using wordpress,
because of the constraints of not able to translate the website using the plugins I had to literally edit the code and display the translated pages.

My problem is - I have added a column in the database and want to use it when a user post a new post from dashboard and that post should be updated in the new column. However I don't know exactly where to replace the new column

**example:**
I want to change the **post_title to post_title_en** where post_title_en is the new column created in wp_posts table.

I will be grateful if anyone could help me with the file location to change the column name.

Comment: Did you trying [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin. Because I believe as per your requirement it should match to you. also We prefer not change existing columns on db, Because it might complicate your work or future implantation.  Alternately we can do is setup different table and setup all the translation handle on that table based.

Comment: currenlty i am using polyang just to insert both translated languages in the database, which is happening correctly for the default language but for the customizing language(which is english) i want the content to be stored in the newly created column.instead of the same column. hope  i am able to clearify waht m trying to do ..thanks